# sqlite database comparison

Tags: sqlite

I am new to databases. I have two sqlite3 databases of same size. I created dumps from both the databases and compared them with diffuse tool. They have zero differences. I have also compared the schema of both the databases & found them to be same. Finally I compared them using "sqlite compare" tool. It shows that both have exactly same data & schema. Yet both of them have different md5sums. I just needed to know what else might be different in them. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. A database can be fragmented, have gaps where rows were deleted which will affect the exact bytes stored on disc but not what a database client sees. This will depend not just on the current state of the database but also it's history: what is the sequence of inserts, updates, deletes etc that lead to the current state.

Operations like `VACUUM` don't change the stored data but do do things like reclaim empty space and so on, which would change the md5 sums.